# How to replace the empty place with next line content in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

```
1,n1,abcd,1234 
2,n2,abrt,5666
 ,h2,yyyy,123x
3,h2,yyyy,123y
3,h2,yyyy,1234
 ,k1,yyyy,5234
4,22,yyyy,5234
```

the above given is my input file abc.txt , all I want the missing first column value  should fill with next row first value.
example:

```
3,h2,yyyy,123x
3,h2,yyyy,123y
```

I want output like below,

```
1,n1,abcd,1234
2,n2,abrt,5666
3,h2,yyyy,123x// the missing first column value 3 should fill with second row first value
3,h2,yyyy,123y
3,h2,yyyy,1234
4,k1,yyyy,5234
4,22,yyyy,5234
```

How to implement this with help of AWK or some other alternate in shell script,please help.

Comment: Will only one line at a time be missing a value? Or can you expect two or more consecutive lines will be missing the first field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^ *$/ {
   p=p RS $0
   next
}
p!="" {
   gsub(RS " +", RS $1, p)
   sub("^" RS, "", p)
   print p
   p=""
} 1' file

1,n1,abcd,1234
2,n2,abrt,5666
3,h2,yyyy,123x
3,h2,yyyy,123y
3,h2,yyyy,1234
4,k1,yyyy,5234
4,22,yyyy,5234
```

Comment: ,h2,yyyy,123x
  ,h2,yyyy,123y
3,h2,yyyy,1234   incase the first two lines also empty then it should take the value from very next line..could u please help

Comment: thanks for your help, but its keeping one line and deleting the other line

Answer (score 1):

I would reverse the file, and then replace the value from the *previous* line:

```
tac filename | awk -F, '$1 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {$1 = prev} {print; prev=$1}' | tac
```

This will also fill in missing values on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed '/^ ,/{N;s/ \(.*\n\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\2\1\2\3/}' infile
1,n1,abcd,1234 
2,n2,abrt,5666
3,h2,yyyy,123x
3,h2,yyyy,123y
3,h2,yyyy,1234
4,k1,yyyy,5234
4,22,yyyy,5234
```

The sed command does the following:

```
/^ ,/ {   # If the line starts with 'space comma'
    N     # Append the next line

    # Extract the value before the comma, prepend to first line
    s/ \(.*\n\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\2\1\2\3/
}
```

BSD sed would require an extra semicolon before the closing brace.

This only works with non-contiguous lines with missing values.